# Ruby modules that contain classes

Tags: ruby

I am working on a project to create a compiler in Ruby, even simple compilers will still have a lot of code. I plan on having classes like `SymbolTable`, `Lexer`,`Parser` etc....

All of these classes perform specific operations, but I would still like to group them under one namespace, is it possible to do this in separate files?

ex:

File#1 SymbolTable.rb

```
module PL0Compiler
  class SymbolTable
     #....
  end
end
```

File#2 Lever.rb

```
module PL0Compiler
  class Lexer
     #....
  end
end
```

Comment: @sawa, Thats what I am asking? I'm looking for the proper way to group related classes into 1 namespace, even though the classes are in separate files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. But it would have taken you less time to try it out than to ask, so it's a weird question. Maybe you don't know how to access it? [Here](https://github.com/JoshCheek/ruby-kickstart/blob/master/session5/notes/05-nesting-classes-and-modules.rb) is a rather elaborate example.

Comment: I have nested modules before in the same source ruby file. I wasn't sure if moving them would change anything. I searched SO but didn't see any examples.

Comment: Ruby doesn't care what file your code was defined in. When it looks up the classes/modules, it does it by searching from whatever class / module you're currently contained within, and then from within the first module you specified and so on down the nest. At the toplevel, you're contained within Object, so classes don't matter.  (note that   location does matter in Rails since it deals with code reloading and it filters your backtraces and so forth)